# Webpack Hot Module Reloading not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

I am developing a React application, using Webpack and Hot Module Reloading. It used to work just fine, but some months ago it stopped working, and I have still not been able to find out why. What I think separates my issue from other issues I have been reading about, is that the connection between the browser and the webpack server seems to be working just fine. When I modify a module, I get the following (below) in the browser console, and when I inspect the source from web developer tools, I can see that the code for the module has indeed been updated.

```
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./Content/modules/app/components/datePicker.js
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

The problem is that the code does not seem to be evaluated, so nothing changes on the page itself. The page does not auto-reload, it does nothing. I have migrated from webpack 1 to webpack 2, but it made no difference. I have tried in many different browsers, and they all behave the same. Other members of my team does not experience the same, running the exact same code, so this is really a mystery to me.

Comment: it's possible that a certain plugin from your editor, or even your editor is causing it not to work, can you try installing a clean atom text editor without  any plugins and see if it works saving in it.

Comment: Using a different editor does not make a difference, and neither does changing to a different browser, nor disabling all browser plugins.

Comment: @KnutMarius have you managed to solve this? I am currently experiencing the exact same problem and cannot find any other mildly similar problems when searching.